# How can I access the last key of this JSON from an API using JavaScript?

Tags: json

I would like to access the key 6/9/22 and I have tried `JSONObject.timeline.cases[1]` but this doesn't work. `JSONObject.timeline.6/9/22` doesn't seem to make sense, and I cannot use that as the API will update the dates every day.

```
{
  "country": "USA",
  "province": [
    "mainland"
  ],
  "timeline": {
    "cases": {
      "6/8/22": 85214036,
      "6/9/22": 85329656
    },
    "deaths": {
      "6/8/22": 1010520,
      "6/9/22": 1010805
    },
    "recovered": {
      "6/8/22": 0,
      "6/9/22": 0
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Specifically, are you asking how to access the property or how to determine which property to access?

Comment: You have to point what language are you using, and you have several  6/9/22. Which of them are you trying to reach?

Comment: Apologies, I am trying to the access the 6/9/22 that is in timelines->cases using javascript

Comment: @KrishnaBisani: Use bracket notation: `obj.timeline.cases['6/9/22']`

Comment: @David, that would work but only for today's case, the API will refresh tomorrow and have 6/10/22 instead. Would fetching today's date and formatting it as a string and passing that as a variable work?

Comment: @KrishnaBisani: That becomes a separate issue, accessing the property vs. determining which property to access.  Depending on the logic of the system you'd have a few options.  If you can safely assume that "today" is the latest then, yes, you can format the current date and use it to access the property.

Comment: @KrishnaBisani Can you show  the json that contains  cases 2/1/22  for example ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the value of the last propery of the cases object, you could do this:

```
JSONObject.timeline.cases[Object.keys( JSONObject.timeline.cases)[Object.keys( JSONObject.timeline.cases).length - 1]]); // 85329656
```